# Performance of Arrays.asList().contains() comparing to several if equals instructions

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

Which on these instructions is better in terms of performance and memory usage :

```
if(val.equals(CONSTANT1) || val.equals(CONSTANT2) ..... || val.equals(CONSTANTn)) {

}
```

OR

```
if(Arrays.asList(CONSTANT1,CONSTANT2, ..... ,CONSTANTn).contains(val)) {

}
```

Comment: What is the type of  CONSTANT1 CONSTANT2...?

Comment: Why do you want to do that ? Why not use a Set ?

Comment: I am using PMD to check the complexity of the code , and having a serie of if / equals statements indicates a high code complexity while using the Arrays.asList().contains() version doesn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better question to ask would be how to write this code more clearly (and faster, if performance actually matters). The answer to that would be a `switch` statement (or possibly even polymorphism, if you want to convert your constants into an enum) or a lookup array.

But if you insist on comparing your two approaces, the first is slightly faster. To see this, let's look at what the second aproach entails:

1. create a new array with the constants, to pass them to the vararg parameter of Arrays.asList
2. create a new list object wrapping that array
3. iterate over that array, comparing each element with equals

The third step is equivalent to your first approach.

Finally, it's worth noting that such an operation will likely take far less than a micro second, so unless you invoke this method millions of times per second, any approach will be fast enough.

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically #1 is faster but insignificantly, because Arrays.asList creates only one object - a list view (wrapper) of the specified array, there is no array copying:

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a) {
return new ArrayList<T>(a);
}

private static class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E>
implements RandomAccess, java.io.Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2764017481108945198L;
private final E[] a;

ArrayList(E[] array) {
        if (array==null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
    a = array;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not using a loop I guess that the number of values is so low that in practice any differences will be irrelevant.

However, having said that, if one was to iterate by hand and use equals() versus asList() and contains()... it would still be the same.

Arrays.asList() returns a private implementation of a list which extends AbstractList and simply wraps around the existing array by reference (no copy is done). The contains() method uses the indexOf() which goes through the array using equals() on each element until it finds a match and then returns it. If you would break on your loop when you find an equals then both implementations would be quite equivalent.

The only difference would be a tiny memory footprint for the additional list structure that Arrays.asList() creates, other than that...

Comment: I am using this version :
if(Arrays.asList(CONSTANT1,CONSTANT2, ..... ,CONSTANTn).contains(val)) {
}
because PMD says that the if /equals version has high code complexity

Comment: Yep, no problem with that. Furthermore, given that both implementations are totally equivalent, I would go for the asList() + contains() approach, you cannot get much cleaner than that.

Answer (score 0):

if(val.equals(CONSTANT1) || val.equals(CONSTANT2) ..... || val.equals(CONSTANTn)) {

}

is the better in terms of performance and memory because the 2nd one will take time to build a list and start searching for the val in that list. Here extra memory is required to maintain the list and also extra time is spent on iterating through the list.Where as the comparing the val with constant will make use of short circuit comparison approach.